# To install Canon Lide 220 scanner

Tags: 14.04, apt, scanner, sane

I am using ubuntu 14.04 , While trying to install the scanner canon Lide220 using the command `sudo apt-get install xsane` the following message appears:

```
E: Could not get lock /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (11: Resource temporarily unavailable)
E: Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/), is another process using it?
```

What can I do to succesfully install it?

Answer (score -1):

This might be caused by the auto-update task in the background, you can just try again a couple minutes later to see if this issue still exist.

Or if you want, you can disable the auto-update by following these steps:

1. Open the Dash
2. Search for "Software & Updates"
3. Select the "Updates" tab.
4. Change "Automatically check for updates" from "Daily" to "Never".

After disabling the auto-update, it will stop the daily task to update the software list. See the reference link for more detail. And you won't be blocked by this (auto-update in the background issue) in the future.

Reference: http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2016/02/how-to-disable-automatic-update-ubuntu

Comment: Again, the following message seen

Comment: [sudo] password for itcell1: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package xsane

Comment: This package is available on 14.04 "universe". Open your "Software & Updates", make sure the "universe" option is enabled in the "Ubuntu Software" tab. Run `sudo apt-get update` after closing "Software & Updates" to update the software list. And try again, if it's still not working, deb file is available [here](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+archive/primary/+files/xsane_0.998-5ubuntu1_amd64.deb) on launchpad. Install it with `sudo dpkg -i xsane_0.998-5ubuntu1_amd64.deb`

Comment: This will 1) not stop the currently running automatic update and 2) disable automatic updates in the future. -1

Comment: Thanks, if you try it tomorrow, this won't happen, right?